# How do I find the retweet count with Twitter4J?

Tags: java, api, twitter, twitter4j

As the title says, I'm using the Twitter4J API and I cannot seem to find how to count the retweets of a "Tweet" instance.

Answer (score 2):

The interface `StatusMethodsAsync` has a `getRetweets()` function (as described [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/StatusMethodsAsync.html#getRetweets%28long%29)) but that only shows the top 100 first retweets of a given tweet. If you know that there are less than 100 retweets this should work. If there are more you have in the interface `TwitterStream` a stream of all retweets (as described [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html#getRetweetStream%28%29)), but that doesn't seem fully functioning, so I wouldn't know then...

But this could get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific count function, but `getRetweetedByIDs` will get you an array of up to 100 user ids who retweeted the tweet. This is a little more light-weight if all you want is the number of retweets. The `IDs` interface also has cursor support if you need to retrieve more than 100, but I have no experience with using those functions.